# Where to set Paperclip.options[:swallow_stderr] = false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rubygems

I'm setting up something done in Rails and want to find out the exact cause why Paperclip is throwing the error:

> [paperclip] An error was received while porcessing...

That's why I want to set Paperclip.options[:swallow_stderr] = false

Where do I need to set that to get more information on the error?

This is the full error:

> Processing TrendsController#update (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-04 17:24:18) [PUT]
>     Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update", "authenticity_token"=>"WZpPerl3dV+edWXhxLiBlNfv3KTFb0fNLVkhF3ZMNXA=", "id"=>"1", "trend"=>{"title"=>"bluiz", "description"=>"uzgz", "image"=>#}}
>
> [paperclip] identify -format %wx%h "C:/Windows/Temp/stream20110104-3660-1j1ap8i-0.jpg[0]" 2>NUL
>
> [paperclip] convert "C:/Windows/Temp/stream20110104-3660-1j1ap8i-0.jpg[0]" -resize "100x140>" "C:/Windows/Temp/stream20110104-3660-1j1ap8i-020110104-3660-rmkivh-0" 2>NUL
>
> [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally set this kind of thing in an initializer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializers

Comment: I created a paperclip.rb-file and put the line mentioned above into it. After restarting Mongrel it didn't seem to worked as there weren't more details.

Comment: I updated the initial question with the full error as shown in the log.

Comment: Try running convert manually - from the DOS prompt to see if that works, unfortunately I have not tried using imagemagick on Windows so cannot really help much here.